Cluster Layer distorts other layers on OpenLayers
I have a layer which displays circles with text on top of it - which is working fine.
Then I recently added another layer with Cluster's (referring this demo) and was able to implement it successfully. But when I enable this cluster layer, it impacts the other layers and distorts the features - the placement, orientation and scale get distorted.
I'm not sure what's causing this though.
Below are screenshots

Before Cluster layer

After cluster layer



NOTE: I also notice that the other layers get distorted only if the cluster layer features are visible in the current zoom extents.


EDIT:
One more point to note is that, I had to use the webmercator projection for the cluster layer to get the features to be placed in the correct location, but the other layers are in different projection. Found this post, this post & this post which talks about this issue.

found this related post, but the solution doesn't seem to be related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/313627/253001
